# SQL How To Select All User And User's Friends Posts

Tags: sql

I need to find all user and user's friends posts. For example: I have a user with ID=0. This user has 3 friends (status = accepted) with ID's=1, 2, 3. I need to select all POSTS where USER_POSTED=0, 1, 2, 3 using one sql query.

The problem is - user can have from zero to infinity friends. I can find all user friends ID:

```
SELECT U.USER_ID
FROM USERS U
         JOIN RELATIONSHIP R
              ON (U.USER_ID = R.USER_ID_FROM OR U.USER_ID = R.USER_ID_TO)
                  AND U.USER_ID != :userId
WHERE R.STATUS = :status
  AND (R.USER_ID_TO = :userId OR R.USER_ID_FROM = :userId);
```

But I have no idea how to find all their posts in one query.

SQL Data Model:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    USER_ID      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_NAME    NVARCHAR2(64),
    REAL_NAME    NVARCHAR2(64),
    EMAIL        NVARCHAR2(64),
    PHONE_NUMBER NVARCHAR2(64),
    BIRTH_DATE   TIMESTAMP,
    POST_ID      NUMBER,
    PASSWORD     NVARCHAR2(16)

);

CREATE TABLE POST
(
    POST_ID          NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    MESSAGE          NVARCHAR2(128),
    DATE_POSTED      TIMESTAMP,
    LOCATION         NVARCHAR2(128),
    USERS_TAGGED     NUMBER,
    USER_POSTED      NUMBER,
    USER_PAGE_POSTED NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT USER_TARGET_FK FOREIGN KEY (USERS_TAGGED) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT USER_POSTED_FK FOREIGN KEY (USER_POSTED) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT USER_PAGE_POSTED_FK FOREIGN KEY (USER_PAGE_POSTED) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE USERS
    ADD CONSTRAINT POST_FK FOREIGN KEY (POST_ID) REFERENCES POST (POST_ID);

CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIP
(
    USER_ID_FROM         NUMBER NOT NULL,
    USER_ID_TO           NUMBER NOT NULL,
    STATUS               NVARCHAR2(256),
    FRIENDS_REQUEST_DATE TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT FK_USER_ONE FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID_FROM) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_USER_TWO FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID_TO) REFERENCES USERS (USER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_RELATIONSHIP PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID_FROM, USER_ID_TO)

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for displaying a post is that it needs to be authored by some `:userId` or by a direct friend of that same user.

```
SELECT p.POST_ID, p.MESSAGE
FROM POST p
WHERE
    p.USER_POSTED = :userId OR
    p.USER_POSTED IN (SELECT USER_ID_FROM FROM RELATIONSHIP
                      WHERE USER_ID_TO = :userId
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT USER_ID_TO FROM RELATIONSHIP
                      WHERE USER_ID_FROM = :userId);
```

Note that I used a union under the assumption that a friend relationship could be in any direction.  If you always store relationships in one direction (e.g. smallest to largest), then the union is redundant.